# Scanf não encerra a leitura

Tags: c, string, matriz

Estou tentando fazer um programa onde ele recebe uma matriz de char e ao final imprima a nova matriz.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int l,c,i,j;

    scanf("%d %d",&l,&c);

    char matriz[l][c],matriz_aux[l][c];

    for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
            scanf("%s",&matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] == '.'){
                matriz_aux[i][j] = 'A';
            }else{
                matriz_aux[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
             printf("%c", matriz_aux[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Exemplo de entrada:

```
10 3
..#
#.#
...
.#.
.##
...
...
#..
..#
#.#
```

Saída esperada para essa entrada:

```
AA#
#A#
AAA
A#A
A##
AAA
AAA
#AA
AA#
#A#
```

Comment: Você está lendo cada célula com `%s`, sendo que aparentemente você gostaria  de ter usada, na verdade, `%c`

Comment: Ou então usar `%s` para ler **toda** a linha

Comment: Sim... Com o %s a entrada só encerrava se fosse duplicado os itens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` com `%s` vai ler a linha toda, portanto bastariam `l` loops. Também, a não ser que você vá precisar de `matriz_aux` para outra coisa ela é superflúa e pode-se diminuir a quantidade de loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int l,c,i,j;

    scanf("%d %d",&l,&c);

    char matriz[l][c];

    for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
        scanf("%s",matriz[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
        if(matriz[i][j] == '.'){
          printf("A");
        } else {
          printf("%c", matriz[i][j]);
        }
      }
      printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/repls/SubstantialBigheartedEngine)

Obs: `scanf` não lê até o final da linha e sim até um caracter white-space (espaços, tab) ou final da linha. Caso se queira esses caracteres na matriz pode-se usar `%[^\n]` ao invés de`%s`.

Comment: O scanf com %s não lê a linha toda. Ele lê até o primeiro espaço em branco encontrado. Poderia explicar melhor esta situação já que se o autor assumir que o %s sempre lê até o final, terá outros problemas.

Answer (score 2):

em vez de `%s` use `%c`   no scanf da matriz.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
        int l,c,i,j;

        scanf("%d %d",&l,&c);

        char matriz[l][c],matriz_aux[l][c];

        for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
                scanf("%c",&matriz[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
                if(matriz[i][j] == '.'){
                    matriz_aux[i][j] = 'A';
                }else{
                    matriz_aux[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
                 printf("%c", matriz_aux[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: É possível usar %s e já ler a linha toda em matriz[i], como fiz na minha resposta.